# como puedo localizar un archivo en c# que cambia de nombre?

Tags: c#

tengo la siguiente duda espero me puedan apoyar, estoy haciendo un programa que valida 3 rutas y localiza 1 archivo en cada una de ellas, compara la fecha de modificación con la fecha del día en curso, si se cumple envía un correo confirmando. Hasta ahí todo bien, el código funciona.
El detalle ahora es que en la 3er ruta hay un archivo que cambia de nombre automáticamente de acuerdo a la fecha, por ejemplo hoy se llama archivo20210515.zip y mañana se llama archivo20210516.zip... como puedo localizarlo si cambia de nombre?
adjunto un ejemplo  de mi código:
gracias.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ruta = @"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\ip.png";
        string ruta2 = @"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\actuales.png";
        string ruta3 = @"C:";
        string correoOrigen = "cuenta_que envia_el_correo";
        string correoDestino = "cuenta_que_recibe";
        string correoDestino2 = "cuenta_que_recibe2";
        string correoDestino3 = "cuenta_que_recibe3";
        string contraseña = "pass_de_la_cuenta_que_envia";
        DateTime F_modificacion = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C: 
\Users\Usuario\Documents\ip.png").Date;
        DateTime F_modificacion2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C: 
\Users\Usuario\Documents\actuales.png").Date;
        DateTime F_modificacion3 = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\").Date;
        DateTime fecha_actual = DateTime.Today;
        //Validacion de ruta 1

        if (File.Exists(ruta) && fecha_actual == F_modificacion)
        {
            MailMessage aMailMessage = new MailMessage(correoOrigen, correoDestino, "Evidencia 
documento ip.png", "se encontro el archivo ip.png");
            MailMessage aMailMessage2 = new MailMessage(correoOrigen, correoDestino2, "Evidencia 
documento ip.png", "se encontro el archivo ip.png");
            MailMessage aMailMessage3 = new MailMessage(correoOrigen, correoDestino3, "Evidencia 
documento ip.png", "se encontro el archivo ip.png");
            SmtpClient aSmtpCliente = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            aSmtpCliente.EnableSsl = true;
            aSmtpCliente.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            aSmtpCliente.Port = 587;
            aSmtpCliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(correoOrigen, 
contraseña);

            aSmtpCliente.Send(aMailMessage);
            aSmtpCliente.Send(aMailMessage2);
            aSmtpCliente.Send(aMailMessage3);
                        }

        else
        {

            MailMessage oMailMessage = new MailMessage(correoOrigen, correoDestino, "Evidencia 
documento ip.png", "Error no se genero el achivo ip.png favor de revisar");
            MailMessage oMailMessage2 = new MailMessage(correoOrigen, correoDestino2, "Evidencia 
documento ip.png", "Error no se genero el achivo ip.png favor de revisar");
            MailMessage oMailMessage3 = new MailMessage(correoOrigen, correoDestino3, "Evidencia 
documento ip.png", "Error no se genero el achivo ip.png favor de revisar");
            SmtpClient oSmtpCliente = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            oSmtpCliente.EnableSsl = true;
            oSmtpCliente.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            oSmtpCliente.Port = 587;
            oSmtpCliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(correoOrigen, 
contraseña);

            oSmtpCliente.Send(oMailMessage);
            oSmtpCliente.Send(oMailMessage2);
            oSmtpCliente.Send(oMailMessage3);
        }
```

// así es como me funciono

```
  string ruta = @"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\ip.png";
    string ruta2 = @"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\actuales.png";
    string ruta3 = @"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\archivo"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".zip"
    string correoOrigen = "cuenta_que envia_el_correo";
    string correoDestino = "cuenta_que_recibe";
    string correoDestino2 = "cuenta_que_recibe2";
    string correoDestino3 = "cuenta_que_recibe3";
    string contraseña = "pass_de_la_cuenta_que_envia";
    DateTime F_modificacion = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\ip.png").Date;
    DateTime F_modificacion2 = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\actuales.png").Date;
    DateTime F_modificacion3 = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C: \Users\Usuario\Documents\archivo""+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+".zip").Date;
    DateTime fecha_actual = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: según lo que indicas tiene un patrón de diseño si te percatas el archivo que cambia de nombre en realidad tiene una fecha... `archivo20210516.zip` me imagino que esto se aplica siempre... lo único que tienes que hacer es buscar el archivo basado en el nombre utilizando la fecha concatenada, algo como `string fileName = "archivo" + FechaActual+".zip"`

Comment: Y el archivo que quieres localizar es el de la fecha actual?

Comment: hola, si en efecto debe localizar el de la fecha mas reciente y esta debe ser igual a la del día en curso.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez no me esta funcionando, pero  pienso que debe ser quizás por el orden de la fecha..  ya que en el archivo se genera como aaaaMMdd y posiblemente este contemplando el horario también.

Comment: muchas gracias por sus comentarios, ya  encontré la solución, al parecer esta funcionando bien, hare las pruebas necesarias. Saludos.

Comment: Pues comparte tu solucion ya que puede serle util a otros

Comment: hiciste lo del nombre del archivo ??? se supone que deben tener el mismo formato de fecha ...